# Hive data import from MySQL dump file

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have some MySQL dumped data in GB's that I have to process using Hive and Hadoop. This dump file is in .sql format. First contains table schema and then, insert statement, to insert all data.

Now, what is the best way to import it into hive. I know about load but it does not work in this case. I am using Hadoop 3 with Hive 3 version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to transfer mysql table to hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632514/how-to-transfer-mysql-table-to-hive)

Comment: In given question case, data is on MySQL server. In my case, it is dump

Comment: You can use RegexSerDe to create table which will read that file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66029247/2700344 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/65616999/2700344